# Does Tor browser work with college network?

Tags: privacy, tor

I'm in a system where my modem connects to a college network (KotNet) that monitors its internet traffic.  Since I'd like some privacy I was wondering if a Tor browser would hide my identity or if it would not work since I first have to log in to the college net (with username and password) before I can have access to internet.

Comment: I think all you need is a VPN subscription.  The college administrators will be able to see that you connected to the VPN, but not what happens after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your college would be able to know that you used Tor and can fairly easily block Tor if they wanted to. But what data goes through the Tor network is most likely out of bound for them.

If your college runs a Tor exit node, and by chance Tor happen to pick the college's exit node, it is possible that they could do some sort of timing attack. But mounting this attack is difficult, and not very worthwhile unless they specifically is already actively monitoring you personally (and even then it's still no definitive proof).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that any internet connection you access that is also tied to you personally (e.g. the login credentials on a college network) can be traced back to you. Therefore it is not suitable for full anonymity online. You enter your login credentials to access the network, the network admins can trace your connections through their network to a Tor node. Theoretically that *should* be all they can see because your traffic should be encrypted. But if your adversary is some No Sugar Added ice cream it might also be monitoring exit traffic of their hosted Tor nodes. This would make you risk a pairing up of your traffic with exit traffic.

If Tor will *connect* is a different question. This would depend on if your ISP (sometimes the college for many universities and colleges) has blacklisted any IPs.

So, it really depends what you need the anonymity for. Investigative journalism critical of your host country? I'd say probably not a good idea. Avoiding the eyes of malicious non-state actors - You're probably okay to use it.

One other thing to consider is if your college bans Tor traffic and what policies regarding this are on your campus.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in obfuscation techniques between yourself and the Tor network I would suggest you look at the pluggable transports "extensions":

https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en

Answer (score -1):

Normally educational networks use webfilters. And to keep the network bandwith at normal rate ,it should be blocked